# Exclude certain screens in React-Navigation/Drawer

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have an app with a login page, I do not want the drawer to appear on this page. Only the ones that come after. I thought I should create two stack navigators. The drawer navigator will wrap one but not the other. I am using the @react-navigation/drawer library I got close:

App.js

```
// Have both navigators at the root
render() {
    return (
    [
    <NavigationContainer>
       <DrawerNavigator extraData={{handleLogin:this.handleLogin, handleLogout:this.handleLogout, checkLoginStatus:this.checkLoginStatus}}/>
    </NavigationContainer>,
    <NavigationContainer>
      <LogRegNavigator extraData={{handleLogin:this.handleLogin, handleLogout:this.handleLogout, checkLoginStatus:this.checkLoginStatus}}/>
    </NavigationContainer>
    ]
     
    );
  }
```

The problem here is that both are rendering which I don't want obviously. Also the problem that they don't actually share the same screen, meaning you can't navigate between stacks.

LogRegNavigator.js:

```
render (){
    return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" >
        {props => <Home {...props} extraData={{handleLogin:this.props.extraData.handleLogin, handleLogout:this.props.extraData.handleLogout, checkLoginStatus:this.props.extraData.checkLoginStatus}}/>}
        </Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
}
```

That's my regular navigator for the login and register screen

MainStackNavigator.js

```
render (){
    return (
    <Stack.Navigator>

            <Stack.Screen name="PractSetup">
            {props =>  <PractSetup {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
            
    )
}
```

That's the main navigator for all the pages after the login/register screens

drawerNavigator.js

```
render () {
    return(
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name='Home'>
        {props => <MainStackNavigator {...props} extraData={{handleLogin:this.props.extraData.handleLogin, handleLogout:this.props.extraData.handleLogout, checkLoginStatus:this.props.extraData.checkLoginStatus}}/>}
        </Drawer.Screen>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
    )

}
```

That's the drawer navigator that wraps the main navigator. That does it's job in excluding the Login/Reg drawer, but now both the navigator stacks are being displayed. There must be a simpler way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How I would approach this is to create a SwitchNavigator that wraps both your DrawerNavigator and LogRegNavigator.
That way in App.js you'll have something like:

```
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
{
    //here you would include your navigators 
    mainFlow: DrawerNavigator,
    logRegFlow: LogRegNavigator
},
{
    //here your options for the stack navigator
    initialRouteName:'logRegFlow'
});
return(
    <NavigationContainer>
        <SwitchNavigator/>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
```

That way the LogRegNavigator will be shown first and you cant start doing some routing.
[StackNavigator Docs.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/switch-navigator/)
[NavigationContainer Docs.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/)

Comment: interesting I havent heard of that, will the routing continue as normal after that? Im going to give it a try

Comment: SwitchNavigator has been deprecated as of 5.x unfortunately. I'm not sure if it's helps anyways. I don't just need to switch between navigators I need to effectively disable a navigator for certain screens

Comment: Okay so you actually set me on the right path I'm dumb. Switching between navigators inherently means that one is disabled when I switch to the other lol. I am able to use the ternary operator to achieve this.